# How can i use isPressed in Label?

Tags: c#, wpf

this is part of my code, i already search it on google but no one know what i mean.

```
 <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="30" Content="" FontFamily="FontAwesome" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Label.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
```

Comment: So, are you going for mouse over or pressed?  Title says one thing, but your code points to something different.  Either way, `EventTrigger` is what you need.

Comment: Excuse me. the main purpose of my question is i need to create animation like this http://i.imgur.com/UwwZya3.png but i don't know what should i search

Comment: Well, that wasn't part of your main question.  Edit your question and try to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `EventTrigger` in this case. If's of course longer but it's the simplest approach using pure standard XAML (not any custom):

```
<Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
       Width="30" Height="30" Content="Clgt?" FontFamily="FontAwesome" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                          <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Duration="0" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                          <ColorAnimation To="Transparent" Duration="0" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>                    
                </EventTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Label.Style>
 </Label>
```

It's even better to use `RemoveStoryboard` action when the `MouseLeftButtonUp` like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <BeginStoryboard Name="bg">
           <Storyboard>
              <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Duration="0" 
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
           </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonUp">
         <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bg"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: the second answer, the background can't return to transparent?

Comment: @kanamichan so what color it is? do you have any `Setter` that can make the background be still in some different color? Such as when the mouse is over, you set the background to some other color. If so that's the correct behavior.